# Cross-language programming - list of equivalent types?

Tags: c#, asp.net, delphi, programming-languages

I do most of my development using Delphi (D7 specifically). I also do some secondary work with ASP.NET / C#. I'm finding myself fighting to convert code from one language to the other, as well as figuring out how to properly publish DLL functions in one side to be called from the other side.

I'm sure there must be some big dictionary of translations between languages - for example...

**Original Delphi Source:**

```
if X = 5 then begin
  S:= IntToStr(1);
end else begin
  S:= IntToStr(-1);
end;
```

**C# Translation:**

```
if (X == 5)
{
  S = (1).ToString();
}
else
{
  S = (-1).ToString();
}
```

**Delphi DLL Function:**

```
function DoSomething(const In: PChar; const zIn: Integer; 
  var Out: PChar; var zOut: Integer): Boolean; stdcall;
```

**C# Import:**

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", CharSet=CharSet.AnsiChar, 
  CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool DoSomething(in string In, in int zIn, 
  out string Out, out int zOut);
```

(Please forgive me if that's incorrect, I typed it by memory not by copy/paste)

I'd love to have some sort of equivalence dictionary between languages, so I know how to match one end up with the other. Anyone know of any good website or book?

Comment: By the way, just looking at my before/after translations above, it reminds me how much more code is involved in C# than there is with Delphi, almost double :P

Comment: [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Programming_Tasks) is a terrific resource for this sort of thing.

Comment: the C# version with the braces on the new lines (that style is optional, by the way) actually has fewer characters.  As for our other example, where is the dll filename specified in Delphi if not done as in C#?

Comment: @JerryDodge on the "C# Import" part, it's significantly longer but is more general than Delphi's. You can do a lot more with it than you can with Delphi's, since it's specialised for just calling convention and dll import. And I think that's missing from the Delphi one, the dll from which to import the function. Edit: Like Kirk said, where is the dll filename.

Comment: Actually, there is notably *less* C# code than Delphi in your code example. You have specifically used the most lines possible with your c# code, but count the actual number of characters. I'm not talking about the imports part; that's a false example, because you only import something once, but may use it over and over.

Comment: @KirkWoll: The dll filename isn't supposed to be there: The first delphi code snippet is publishing a function inside of a DLL - whereas the second C# snippet is calling that function in the DLL.

Comment: I could just as easily do similar things in Delphi using the unit names, such as `DT := DateUtils.Yesterday` or 'S := StrUtils.StringReplace(....)` - but it all seems kinda forced with C# - there's many things which are required to put in C# which is optional to put in Delphi...

Comment: @JerryDodge So those code snippets are not equivalent. (though, maybe you weren't claiming they were?)

Comment: @JerryDodge But we just showed you those things are not required in C#. It's a false argument, anyway. Characters of code typed is hardly an important metric for comparing languages. (I do note you put that comparison in a comment, not the question. But still... you wer wrong :P )

Comment: I had no intention to start a discussion about the size of the code, that was just a comment I thought I'd point out. The main thing I need is help matching certain types up between the languages, for example, to publish a Delphi DLL function with a String to be called from C#, you can't publish it as a `String` in Delphi, but rather as a `PChar` with a corresponding `Size of PChar` variable. In C#, PChar translates to a string. Integer matches to an int. Delphi `Boolean` cannot be used with C#, but instead `bool` is required. These are the things I mean.

Comment: Your P/invoke translation is surely wrong and illustrates why there can be no automatic translator for P/invoke. The `PChar` param is the issue. As it stands it would only work if the memory was allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc`. If you want to make life easier for interop, use COM.

Comment: I'm not asking for an automatic translator, I'm asking for resources to help me understand what matches up with what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled across **[this article](http://www.glennstephens.com.au/tech/CSharp4DelphiDevelopers.pdf)** today, which covers basically exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Reflector to decompile most .net assembly into a variety of languages, include c# and object pascal. It is a good way to compare one to the other.

http://www.reflector.net/

by the way, the size of code seems about the same to me

```
if X = 5 then begin
  S:= IntToStr(1);
end else begin
  S:= IntToStr(-1);
end;
```

vs.

```
if (X == 5) {
  S = (1).ToString();
} else {
  S = (-1).ToString();
}
```

70 characters vs. 61 characters.

Or even...

```
s = (x == 5) ? ""+1 : ""+(-1);
```

(the above line is only for fun. It would be better to use 1.ToString() etc. because ""+1 results in boxing the int and sending that as the single parameter to Concat(object) which then does the ToString() on it. It's more efficient to just call the ToString() directly on the int.)

Comment: The C# could actually be further reduced in this specific case; the brackets could be removed (though I wouldn't recommend it)

Comment: yeah, I almost did that but thought it made the point best to simply fix the line formatting. But I think I'll add it anyway now.

Comment: Same for the Object Pascal, you can remove the begin...end's in this case.

Comment: But no ternary conditional operator...IfThen is not quite the same because IfThen(x = 0, 0, 1/x) fails since all terms are evaluated.

Comment: Looks great, I just wish there were some free resources ;)

Comment: Removing the brackets `{ }` from the C# code would be the same as removing `begin` and `end` from the Delphi code.

Comment: The version 6 of Reflector is still free, but since it is not available for download, it's only free if you were already using the free version. http://eon.businesswire.com/news/eon/20110426007021/en/.NET-Reflector/Reflector/Red-Gate

Comment: Actually, when you remove all the un-required spaces, Delphi=70 and C#=55 characters... But yes the C# for loop is a nightmare, I always get confused with it...

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of CLSCompliant attribute.

If you want to provide interop, you just need to ensure that your class's public APIs conform to the CLS compliance.  I'm not sure if you can run FXCop against a delphi assembly but if you declare CLSCompliant Attribute it will complain when it runs into violations.

Answer (score -2):

you can go to [developerfusion][1][1]: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-python/ to find out how to translate source code between languages.

Comment: post this answer if anybody ask the same question with python tag